# How to exclude the last word after the regex match?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-negation, grok

This is not a part of python or java programming but part of grok patterns. I have an incoming data to the field in the below format

1. `online market failure ACC20ZM::Test::BNC099`
2. `online market failure;Test;BNC099`

I need to extract the data until first occurring special characters `;` or `:` excluding the character itself.
The expected output is `online market failure`
I was able to get this is for the second format using `^([^:|;])+` but the first one will return `online market failure ACC20ZM` as expected and I am trying to exclude ACC20ZM in that.

**Note:** The message in the field is not fixed and it keeps changing(including the word I am trying to exclude) so there is no fixed number of words. Also, It is a single field getting data in the above format( either 1st type or 2nd type but not both the type at a time). I am trying to write a regex pattern that should be able to handle both the formats. I am especially looking for help to exclude the word after the match using a mentioned regex pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one;

```
^([^:|;])+(?=(\s\w*:|;))
```

Comment: I tried this and it gives ```ACC20ZM::Test::BNC099``` but I want to exclude this i.e I need output as ```online market failure```

Comment: Can you check from here; https://regex101.com/r/W7vbAv/1

Comment: Thanks. I was looking at the after-match result in grok constructor and got confused. This works as expected.